# Add numbers with duplicate values for columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df:
col1     col2
 1        pqr
 3        abc
 2        pqr
 4        xyz
 1        pqr
```

I found that there is duplicate value and its pqr. I want to add 1,2,3 where pqr occurs. The final data frame I want to achieve is:

```
df1
col1      col2
 1        pqr1
 3        abc
 2        pqr2
 4        xyz
 1        pqr3
```

How to do it in efficient way

Comment: The only dupe is `pqr`?

Comment: yes. Its only dupe

Comment: @KallolSamanta - And this solution working nice?

Comment: yes, Thanks, working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupe rows and add counter created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
mask = df['col2'].duplicated(keep=False)
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] += df.groupby('col2').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Or:

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col2'].duplicated(keep=False), 
                      df['col2'] + df.groupby('col2').cumcount().add(1).astype(str),
                      df['col2'])
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     1  pqr1
1     3   abc
2     2  pqr2
3     4   xyz
4     1  pqr3
```

If need same only for `pqr` values:

```
mask = df['col2'] == 'pqr'
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] += pd.Series(np.arange(1, mask.sum() + 1),
                                  index=df.index[mask]).astype(str)
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     1  pqr1
1     3   abc
2     2  pqr2
3     4   xyz
4     1  pqr3
```

Comment: Wow..!! Too fast..:D

Comment: Man! All the ways I tried to solve this! Thanks a ton! I knew there was something to do with groupby(), but the np.where() function didn't even occur to me. Thank you again!