# python dataframe change index type and remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe that looks like this

```
2020-01-01                            10
2020-02-01                            5
2020-05-01                            2
2020-08-01                            7
2020-01-01  00:00:00                  0
2020-02-01  00:00:00                  0
2020-03-01  00:00:00                  0
2020-04-01  00:00:00                  0
```

I want to remove the time of the index and combine where the dates may be the same the end result will look like

```
2020-01-01                            10
2020-02-01                            5
2020-03-01                            0
2020-04-01                            0
2020-05-01                            2
2020-06-01                            0
2020-07-01                            0
2020-08-01                            7
etc, etc
```

Comment: When you say combine to you mean add the values?

Comment: If so then it is just [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105419/add-numbers-with-duplicate-values-for-columns-in-pandas) after you apply a [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behav)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the index data type and filter with `.duplicated`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
df
Out[1]: 
             1
0             
2020-01-01  10
2020-02-01   5
2020-05-01   2
2020-08-01   7
2020-03-01   0
2020-04-01   0
```

If you want to sum them together rather than get rid of the duplicate, then use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.sum(level=0)
df
Out[2]: 
             1
0             
2020-01-01  10
2020-02-01   5
2020-05-01   2
2020-08-01   7
2020-03-01   0
2020-04-01   0
```

Comment: what does ~df.index.duplicated(keep='first') this part do

Comment: It returns a boolean array of: `array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])`, which you can then use within square brackets to filter out the duplicate rows which are the `False` ones. Getting rid of duplicates on the index isn't as straightforward as getting rid of duplicates in a normal column.

Answer (score 0):

if the index content is in string format u can simply slice

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)#consider column name to be date
df["date"]=df["date"].str[:11]#till time index
df.set_index( "date",inplace=True)
```

if it is in date format:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df.set_index( "date",inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this data (reflecting your own) with the string dates and int data in columns (not as index):

```
dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-05-01',  '2020-08-01',
         '2020-01-01  00:00:00', '2020-02-01  00:00:00', '2020-03-01  00:00:00',
         '2020-04-01  00:00:00']
data = [10,5,2,7,0,0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'data':data})
```

You can do the following:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).dt.date #convert to datetime and get the date
df = df.groupby('dates').sum().sort_index() # groupby and sort index
```

Giving:

```
            data
dates           
2020-01-01    10
2020-02-01     5
2020-03-01     0
2020-04-01     0
2020-05-01     2
2020-08-01     7
```

You can replace `.sum()` with your favorite aggregation method.  Also, if you want to impute the missing dates (as in your expected output), you can do:

```
months = pd.date_range(min(df.index), max(df.index), freq='MS').date
df = df.reindex(months).fillna(0)
```

Giving:

```
            data
dates           
2020-01-01  10.0
2020-02-01   5.0
2020-03-01   0.0
2020-04-01   0.0
2020-05-01   2.0
2020-06-01   0.0
2020-07-01   0.0
2020-08-01   7.0
```